How to count the number of time series data for multiple device groups in Apache IoTDB?
Is there a way to implement count(column) group by column in Apache IoTDB? I need to group the devices and count the number of timeseries data in each device group. I want to know are there any method that can be used to achieve this? Can I calculate the number in different groups using one query statement, or I can only do the group calculation one by one?

Currently, Apache IoTDB can count the number of time series data based on one device level, so you can use count(data) align by device and sum all the results up to get the total number you need.
